# Google search won't recognize symbols

Tags: java, calculator, symbols

There is this website that gives java program examples (https://www.edureka.co/blog/java-programs/#CalculatorPrograminJava).

On the first question, it talks about Java Calculator, there is this line where I can't understand so I tried to search it on Google "%c",

`System.out.printf("%.1f %c %.1f = %.1f", first, operator, second, result);`

it doesn't even include the symbol on the search result but it shows me a different result instead. I think this % is not a modulo on this example but it is used to tell java that you're declaring something else. I know that "f" stands for float but I don't know what is "c" is. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I suggest you read the _javadoc_ for method `printf()` in class [`java.io.PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to find in Google is Java's format string syntax. Here is it: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax. Look at the table in this section, named "Conversions", and you'll see, that `c` stands for "Unicode character". So, your format string means that it will print `operator` argument as a usual character.